# Change CSRF token after Submission and Validation Form

Tags: php, symfony, token, csrf, csrf-protection

How change csrf token in Symfony2/3 when form was submitted, validated and saved form's data to server?

```
// AppController.php
...
public function saveAction(Request $request) {
    $event = new Data();
    $form = $this->createForm(DataForm::class, $event);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $creator = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:User')
            ->find($this->getUser()->getId());
        $event->setCreator($creator);
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($event);
        $entityManager->flush();
```

> < SOMETHING HERE to change csrf token. ANY IDEAS? >

```
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('event_view', ['id' => $event->getId()]));
    }
    $message = ['text' => 'Wrong data to save', 'type' => 'danger'];
    $this->get('session')->set('messages', [$message]);
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('event_create'));
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be regenerating the CSRF token automatically.  The only reason I could think that you may want to do this would be if you submit the form with ajax and for whatever reason needed to get the next token:
In your form type:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        //...other defaults
        'intention'       => 'data_form_intention',
    ));
}
```

In your saveAction:

```
$csrf = $this->get('security.csrf.token_manager');     
$token = $csrf->refreshToken("data_form_intention");
```

Comment: OptionsResolverInterface are deprecated. I used class OptionsResolver with _'csrf_token_id'_ instead _'intention'_. Thanks. Its work